# How to avoid onchange event of a form when a particular input field is changed?

Tags: javascript

I have a form with `onchange` event attached to it. Inside the form, I have a couple of input fields whose changes will be validated on change.

But inside the same form, I have a select and input field, whose change should not matter to the form. They are there just for dynamically adding more form fields.

So my question is, what can I do to avoid triggering `onchange` event when either of the select or that particular input field is changed?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Give the "unimportant" fields a class name (e.g. class="unimportant"). In your `onchange` handler, only do the validation if the element that triggered the event does not have a class of `unimportant`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`change` events "bubble up" from elements in the form on which they are fired.

There are two ways of ignoring the unwanted change events.

1. In the  `change` event handler of the form, check the `event` object's `target` property. If it is one of the form elements to ignore, return from the handler without doing anything.

   You could check `className`, `classList` or `id` properties of `event.target` to identify ignored elements.
2. Explicitly call `event.preventPropagation()` in `change` event handlers added to the elements whose changes should not reach the form handler.

See also [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) and [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement @kmosers suggestion like so.

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if(!event.target.classList.contains("nochange")) {
        console.log("fire change for me");
    } else {
        console.log("no change event for me");
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <select class="nochange">
                <option>option 1</option>
                <option>option 2</option>
                <option>option 3</option>
                <option>option 4</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```